# Troubleshoot Google App Engine 500 internal server error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Is there any way to properly troubleshoot GAE 500 server errors? I know I can check from console.developers.google.com -> Monitoring -> logs, but they do not tell much. Only same thing that I can get from the browser network response 500 internal server error.

What I am looking for is the similar log to apache.log or php.log that would actually print a stacktrace of an error or an exception that happened in app.

Comment: These answers are out of date now.. (some three years later). Look for the Error Reporting panel in the google cloud platform dashboard.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The previous answers are out of date now (some three years later).
Look for the Error Reporting panel in the google cloud platform dashboard.

You will get a stack trace to the problem in your code (if the problem is in your code and I suppose you probably need to be logging errors to std err).  A stack trace should help you debug a 500 error.  Here's a stack trace that I just received ...

```
ImportError: No module named flask_assistant

at <module> (/base/data/home/apps/f~XXXX/20180209t180735.407529010683953771/main.py:31)
at LoadObject (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:85)
at _LoadHandler (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:299)
at Handle (/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27/a7637d5531ec9deb_unzipped/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py:240)
```

That's how to get a stack trace in the event of a 500 error.

Comment: Yes. I read this answer but never followed it for some reason. Go in App engine dashboard and look for client errors, server errors. It will tell you. In my case I was referencing js and css files (that did not exist) in my html file. works fine on localhost, but errors on GAE

Answer (score 4):

There's unfortunately no straightforward answer to this.

Normally, a 500 is something about which you cannot do much, as it's an error internal to the Google servers. The most we suggest is to have an [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff?hl=en) to your requests, so that our infrastructure can "correct" the issue itself (which it usually does, and does pretty quickly).

Sometimes, some errors will throw 500 for specific behaviors (like sending a wrong format of file or a wrong variable type to a specific product). In these case, the error should be clearer. If it isn't, try to gather as much info as possible and then post it on our [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) that this error could be phrased with more info than "500"

Comment: Thanks for you answer Patrice, even though its not the one I was hoping to get. Appreciate also the tips.