# AppEngine - Client closed keepalive connection

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, symfony

I have deployed my Symfony 4 app to Google App Engine (Flexible environment).

The build seems to have worked, but loading the app on in Chrome results in error:

```
Oops! An Error Occurred
The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

The app engine log is here:

```
 2019/02/02 04:33:13 [info] 9#9: *6 client 172.17.0.4 closed keepalive connection
 A 
 GET 404 191 B 0 ms Chrome 71 /favicon.ico A  GET 404 191 B 0 ms Chrome 71
 GET 500 930 B 6 ms Chrome 71 /connect/google A  GET 500 930 B 6 ms Chrome 71
 GET 307 316 B 6 ms Chrome 71 / A  GET 307 316 B 6 ms Chrome 71
 172.17.0.4 - - [02/Feb/2019:04:32:13 +0000] "GET /connect/google HTTP/1.1" 500 930 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
 A 
 172.17.0.4 - - [02/Feb/2019:04:32:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 307 316 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
 A 
 2019/02/02 04:29:08 [info] 9#9: *1 client 172.17.0.4 closed keepalive connection
 A 
 GET 500 930 B 6 ms Chrome 71 /connect/google A  GET 500 930 B 6 ms Chrome 71
 GET 307 316 B 5 ms Chrome 71 / A  GET 307 316 B 5 ms Chrome 71
 172.17.0.4 - - [02/Feb/2019:04:28:08 +0000] "GET /connect/google HTTP/1.1" 500 930 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
 A 
 172.17.0.4 - - [02/Feb/2019:04:28:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 307 316 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
 A 
 GET 404 191 B 10 ms Chrome 71 /favicon.ico A  GET 404 191 B 10 ms Chrome 71
 GET 500 930 B 207 ms Chrome 71 /connect/google A  GET 500 930 B 207 ms Chrome 71
 172.17.0.4 - - [02/Feb/2019:04:27:50 +0000] "GET /connect/google HTTP/1.1" 500 930 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
 A 
 GET 307 316 B 271 ms Chrome 71 / A  GET 307 316 B 271 ms Chrome 71
 172.17.0.4 - - [02/Feb/2019:04:27:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 307 316 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
 A 
A  2019-02-02 03:22:43,817 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)

A  2019-02-02 03:22:43,817 INFO success: php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)

A  [02-Feb-2019 03:22:42] NOTICE: ready to handle connections

A  [02-Feb-2019 03:22:42] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 7

A  2019/02/02 03:22:42 [notice] 8#8: start worker process 9

A  2019/02/02 03:22:42 [notice] 8#8: start worker processes

A  2019/02/02 03:22:42 [notice] 8#8: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 65536:65536

A  2019/02/02 03:22:42 [notice] 8#8: OS: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64

A  2019/02/02 03:22:42 [notice] 8#8: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

A  2019/02/02 03:22:42 [notice] 8#8: using the "epoll" event method

A  2019-02-02 03:22:42,339 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 8

A  2019-02-02 03:22:42,338 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 7

A  2019-02-02 03:22:41,335 INFO supervisord started with pid 1

A  2019-02-02 03:22:41,329 WARN No file matches via include "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/*.conf"

A  2019-02-02 03:22:41,329 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
```

I don't understand this error. How can I resolve?

Comment: App Engine 500 (Internal Server Error) almost always means that your code threw an unhanded exception that was caught by the runtime. Therefore I would suggest to check your php code .

Answer (score 1):

As clarified in this other similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451696/appengine-500-server-error-after-deploy-error-in-code), this type of issue, indeed, is related to the code, where it's not well written and then, the runtime is caughting the exception from it. In this situation, it's recommended to take a look at your code and look for exceptions that are not being handled by your code.

An alternative is to check in the Cloud Dashboard - as mentioned [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/726978/troubleshoot-google-app-engine-500-internal-server-error) - for more details in the Error Reporting, so you can get more information from the stack trace.